# Print the commit history of just one line with linebreaks after each commit?

Tags: bash, git, scripting, git-log

I'm attempting to write a bash script that prints out N for each line in a file, where N is the number of times that line has been edited in a commit. That is, for a five-line file where the first line was changed 4 times and the rest were only added (i.e. just one commit), the script would output:

```
4
1
1
1
```

So far, I'm able to log file changes on each individual line:

```
CTR=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((CTR++))
    echo $(git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" -L $CTR,$CTR:"$1")
done < "$1"
```

but when I print the results, each line's commit history only takes up one line of the results (the second line below contains the entire multi-commit history for the second line of the file):

```
2182a65 Anonymous Fri Mar 23 14:34:36 2018 -0400 second commit diff --git a/hello.py b/hello.py --- a/hello.py +++ b/hello.py @@ -0,0 +1,1 @@ +This is the second commit.
1814257 Anonymous Fri Mar 23 14:35:26 2018 -0400 Fourth commit diff --git a/hello.py b/hello.py --- a/hello.py +++ b/hello.py @@ -2,1 +2,1 @@ -This is the third commit. +This is the fourth commit now! c3f1021 Anonymous Fri Mar 23 14:34:59 2018 -0400 Third commit diff --git a/hello.py b/hello.py --- a/hello.py +++ b/hello.py @@ -2,0 +2,1 @@ +This is the third commit.
c3f1021 Anonymous Fri Mar 23 14:34:59 2018 -0400 Third commit diff --git a/hello.py b/hello.py --- a/hello.py +++ b/hello.py @@ -2,0 +3,1 @@ +This is also the third commit.
```

I was planning on tracking # of commits per line by counting the number of rows for each line's history, but this is making that impossible.

How do I print the commit history of just one line with linebreaks after each commit?

Answer (score 0):

It's your:

```
echo $(...)
```

that is eating the newlines.  Remember, `$(...)` runs the command in the parentheses, then applies additional substitution rules, as described in [the `Command Substitution` section of the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting. ...
>
> If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the results.

Since there are no double quotes here, word splitting and filename expansion *are* performed on the results.  This is what deletes the newlines.

---

Something that's worth thinking about here: Git does not have *file* history.  Git has commits, and commits *are* history, and commits have files.  To produce a faked-up file history, Git winds up comparing each commit to its parent.  Diffing `1234567:file.ext` against `89abcde:file.ext` tells you what changed in `file.ext` when you moved from commit `1234567` (the parent) to commit `89abcde` (the child).

This all makes a great deal of sense, and works just as everyone expects, for ordinary commits, which have only one parent.  For *merge* commits, however, the commit has two parents.  Comparing the specific file in the child against one or the other parent often produces a *different answer*.  Which parent(s) should be used?  The `git log` utility has several different answers available, depending on what rule you think should apply.  See [the **History Simplification** section of the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_history_simplification) for details.